# PHP exec command is not working with terminal command containing variable

Tags: php, linux, variables, exec

I am using following php code.

```
$i = "1TEN";
$val=exec('cat '$i'.dssp -n | grep " ACC " | grep "[0-9]\+" -o | head -n 1');
echo $val;
```

It doesn't give any error or any output. However, following code works well:

```
$val=exec('cat 1TEN.dssp -n | grep " ACC " | grep "[0-9]\+" -o | head -n 1');
echo $val;
```

Can anyone help ?

Similarly,

```
$line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $diff | awk -F" " -v var=$pos '{if ($2==var) print FNR}");
```

Comment: them quotes look weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this mistake because you are inserting variable in a string in a wrong way – you should use double quotes `"` to specify your string and escape `"` in a text with `\` so it won't be interpreted as the end of a string:

```
$val = exec("cat {$i}.dssp -n | grep \" ACC \" | grep \"[0-9]\+\" -o | head -n 1");
```

*or* use use double quotes `"` to specify your string and replace `"` in text with single quotes`'`:

```
$val = exec("cat {$i}.dssp -n | grep ' ACC ' | grep '[0-9]\+' -o | head -n 1");
```

If you want to use single quotes `'` you can concatenate you string like it is shown below :

```
$val = exec('cat ' . $i . ' .dssp -n | grep " ACC " | grep "[0-9]\+" -o | head -n 1');
```

Comment: I have a similar problem in following line: $line=exec("tail {$i}.dssp -n {$diff} | awk -F\" \" -v var={$pos} '{if ({$pos}==var) print FNR}");

Comment: YES Thanks.. But I am still having problem with the following one: $line=exec("tail {$i}.dssp -n {$diff} | awk -F\" \" -v var={$pos} '{if ({$pos}==var) print FNR}"); Whats the problem in this one ?

Comment: @Om Shiv: Is `if ({$pos}==var) print FNR` for shell or for php to evaluate?

Comment: Its an awk command which i need to evaluate using PHP script file.

Comment: @Om Shiv : you should escape curly braces like `\\{` and `\\}`

Comment: It did not work... I have asked it as a new question here. Please check, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728324/php-exec-command-is-not-working-with-awk-command

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes on the outside to allow variable interpolation, and use single quotes on the inside.

```
$val=exec("cat $i.dssp -n | grep ' ACC ' | grep '[0-9]\+' -o | head -n 1");
```