# PHP exec command is not working with awk command

Tags: php, awk, exec

I have following code:

```
$eff=40;
$pos=34;

$line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk -F" " -v var=$pos '{if ($2==var) print FNR}'");
```

Please help...

Comment: What are you trying to solve? What is going wrong?

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes after `-F`\

Comment: @shuttle87, You will have to look at his previous question to understand the context for this one.

Comment: @merlin2011, A link to the previous question would have been an extremely good thing to include in the question because I Was not aware of that context

Comment: @shuttle87, I could not agree more. That's why *I* put in a link in my answer to make it more clear to future readers.

Comment: Actually, I did not mean to create confusion in previous post, as this problem was specific to syntax used by awk. some people suggested to use // along with curly brackets...which again did not solve the problem. Hence, started a new post. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23727890/391161), you can fix this easily by using single quotes on the inside.

PHP Code

```
<?php
$eff=40;
$pos=34;
$i = 'hello';
$line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk -F' ' -v var=$pos '{if ($2==var) print FNR}'");
print "$line\n";
?>
```

Sample Input (`hello.dssp`):

```
foobar 34
```

Sample Output:

```
1
```